# Using Media Queries and the additive method and how to name classes?

Tags: css, media-queries

My question is regarding using media queries and a very simple example below to determine one thing that i haven't seen anyone mention in particular.

When starting with the smallest viewport, say 320px for example, you can see how your content renders and flows at that size and then begin to drag your browser wider to see where your design breaks and add another media query.

So using this additive method (adding classes as your viewport gets larger not smaller) new styles would have to be added and since all the new classes that you add for the wider viewport sizes are added on top of the base styles that one would of created at the smallest viewport sizes i get a little confused.

The confusion lies in a targeted example.

Say I have a set of classes for my "nav" element at the 320px viewport size, and at the 624px viewport size i wanted to apply another navigation to display?

Would i create a new class name to the "nav" element that would render those styles or could i use the same class name but just add the new styles to it?

That's the question, just about how the class naming would be affected.

So here's my code example to illustrate the point:

First example: would i just use one class name in the code and then based on the targeted media query use the same class name but add new styles to it (that i assume would override the styles of the smaller viewport size) so that it renders differently?

```
<nav class="main">

<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Learn More</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

Or add another classname(s) to the element so that there is no conflict:

In this example i added additional class names from the beginning (medium, large, x-large) and each of those classes would trigger a different media query based on the viewport size.

```
<nav class="main medium large x-large">

<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Learn More</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

Is this a good way to approach the problem, or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would i create a new class name to the "nav" element that would render those styles or could i use the same class name but just add the new styles to it?

You use the same selectors, you just add different styles for the different media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same class, changing the CSS as needed with each media query. This will help keep your markup cleaner and your code more maintainable.

Each subsequent media query will override the styles of the last query. An advantage of this is that you only need to define exactly those properties that need to change from one query to the next. In this example, only the `background-color` needs to change so the `border` doesn't have to be explicitly redefined in every query- the original `border` style will still be used.

See a working example in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GBR8d/.

## HTML

```
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Learn More</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

## CSS

```
.main {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .main {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 624px) {
    .main {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle that makes great sense!